# Better way to write than stacking V-On elements within each other?

Tags: json, vue.js

I have a small thing I'm working on involving JSON data, and I don't really know why, but it won't let me work with the data until I get to a second level of the v-on statements. It looks very unclean to me and I can't imagine this is the best way to accomplish this.

```
<element v-on="item in json">
<element v-on="item2 in item">
{{item2}}
</element>
</element>
```

What is the better way to do this?

Comment: Show the JSON .

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `v-for` (instead of `v-on`).

Comment: show us the related JSON and maybe we can help you